# Spring Social-Java application for accessing LinkedIn data

Tags: java, maven, linkedin-api, spring-social

I am developing a twitter application using java and spring social as a maven project. When i run the code it shows the following exception!!

[image]

My java part code

**Application.java**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

 /*
 * SPRING BOOTSTRAP MAIN
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

**HelloCantroller.java**

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.social.connect.UserProfile;
import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedIn;
import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedInProfile;
import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.impl.LinkedInTemplate;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
private LinkedIn linkedin;

UserProfile userProfile;

@Inject
public HelloController(LinkedIn linkedin) {
    this.linkedin = linkedin;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String helloLinkedIn(Model model) {
    if (!linkedin.isAuthorized()) {
        return "redirect:/connect/linkedin";


    }



    LinkedInProfile profile = linkedin.profileOperations().getUserProfile();

    String profileId = linkedin.profileOperations().getProfileId();
System.out.println(profileId);


    return "hello";
}

}
```

**Html pages**

**LinkedinConnect.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello LinkedIn</title>
 </head>
<body>
    <h3>Connect to LinkedIn</h3>

    <form action="/connect/linkedin" method="POST">
  <!--          <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="read_stream" /> -->
        <div class="formInfo">
            <p>You aren't connected to LinkedIn yet. Click the button to connect this   application with your Facebook account.</p>
        </div>
        <p><button type="submit">Connect to Facebook</button></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**LinkedInConnected.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello Facebook</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Connected to Facebook</h3>

    <p>
        You are now connected to your Facebook account.
        Click <a href="/">here</a> to see some entries from your Facebook home feed.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can i fix the above error and make my code runnable?

Answer (score 0):

in LinkedinConnect.html 
        uncomment           input type="hidden" name="scope" value="read_stream" 
        since the model wil refer to the map object referred by the value read_stream